# onclick dropdown image change Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice in Jquery and JS. I have a dropdown in my Keen template where it shows 2 flags in dropdown. I want to click on dropdown and choose the corresponding flag. I did my research, but all of them are using `select` and `options` tag. My code is using ul and li tag. I want to do it with Jquery. Here is my code in Keen :

```
<div class="kt-header__topbar-item kt-header__topbar-item--langs">
    <div class="kt-header__topbar-wrapper" data-toggle="dropdown" data-offset="10px,0px">
            <span class="kt-header__topbar-icon">
                <img alt="english" src="{% static 'main/media/flags/020-america.svg' %}"/>
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fit dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-anim dropdown-menu-top-unround">
        <ul class="kt-nav kt-margin-t-10 kt-margin-b-10 country-dropdown">
            <li class="kt-nav__item kt-nav__item--active">
                <a href="#" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img alt="english"
                                                         src="{% static 'main/media/flags/020-america.svg' %}"/></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text">English</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="kt-nav__item">
                <a href="#" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img alt="norwegian"
                                                         src="{% static 'main/media/flags/021-norway.svg' %}"/></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text">Norwegian</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?  Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please also add the jquery code you are using that isn't giving you the desired results.

Comment: I couldn't understood how will I write jquery without select and options tag. I don't have the jquery portion.

Comment: I need help on how to lead

Comment: Can you clear up for me what exactly you want to achieve? Click on the dropdown, choose a language and then only show the clicked item? Can you show a picture how it is looking currently? (is kt-nav__item--active the class to only show this item?)

Comment: I am so sorry, this is my first time here. it now looks like this (https://imgur.com/86AE26D). I by default shows the USA flag. I want to click on Norway and show the Norway flag, same for the USA flag. I understood how to work with select and options tag, but I am confused how to do this with list and un ordered lists, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

from your question I cannot elaborate proper solution, but I tried to guess that you might have been looking for something like this

```js
 $(".country-dropdown li").on("click", function(){
  var li = $(this).attr("id");
  
  if(!$("#"+li).hasClass("kt-nav__item--active")){
   
   $("#"+li).prev().removeClass("kt-nav__item--active");
   $("#"+li).next().removeClass("kt-nav__item--active");
   
   $("#"+li).addClass("kt-nav__item--active");
   
   var srcImg = $("#"+li+" a span img").attr("src");
   console.log(srcImg);
   $("#setIcon span img").attr({ "src": srcImg });
  }
  
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="kt-header__topbar-item kt-header__topbar-item--langs">
    <div class="kt-header__topbar-wrapper" id="setIcon" data-toggle="dropdown" data-offset="10px,0px">
            <span class="kt-header__topbar-icon">
                <img alt="english" src="{% static 'main/media/flags/020-america.svg' %}"/>
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fit dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-anim dropdown-menu-top-unround">
        <ul class="kt-nav kt-margin-t-10 kt-margin-b-10 country-dropdown">
            <li class="kt-nav__item kt-nav__item--active" id="eng">
                <a href="#" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img alt="english"
                                                         src="{% static 'main/media/flags/020-america.svg' %}"/></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text">English</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="kt-nav__item" id="no">
                <a href="#" class="kt-nav__link">
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-icon"><img alt="norwegian"
                                                         src="{% static 'main/media/flags/021-norway.svg' %}"/></span>
                    <span class="kt-nav__link-text">Norwegian</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as a quick and dirty solution it does the following; if you click on a li element you get the ID and then it looks up if it's on the active state if not it adds active state and removes it from previous element and then it gets the src from the IMG and sets this in the main IMG, hope this helps